# File downloading - negative file length

Tags: java, android

I am trying to download a file (mp3) from my server.

I want to show the downloading progress, but I am facing a problem that whole time the file size is `-1`.

The screenshot:
[image]

My code:

```
try {
    URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
    // URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.connect();
    int fileSize = connection.getContentLength();
    if (fileSize == -1)
        fileSize = connection.getHeaderFieldInt("Length", -1);
    InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(myFile);

    byte data[] = new byte[1024];
    long total = 0;
    int count;
    while ((count = is.read(data)) != -1) {
        total += count;
        Log.d("fileSize", "Lenght of file: " + fileSize);
        Log.d("total", "Lenght of file: " + total);
        // publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileSize));
        publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / fileSize));
        os.write(data, 0, count);
    }
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    is.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I get the  garbage value  for the `fileSize` which return `-1` (`int fileSize = connection.getContentLength();`)

Comment: Use a command-line tool like **`curl`** to examine the headers coming back from the server when you download this URL manually. Perhaps the server is not setting any length-related headers.

Comment: Sometimes the Length is unknown - it depends on the server side. Nothing wrong with your solution

Comment: @Prosanto As I see, even tho it doesn't show up correctly it should download. Is the downloaded file working?

Comment: Do you compress the stream? If so, the size will be unknown (-1)

Comment: @ Matei Trandafir,Yes downloaded file  working well.And i can able to save in to sd .

Comment: I would not use Integer as file length but long. But even if you stick to it it might just be unknown, nothing much you can do (besides not showing the number/progress).

Comment: Also, if the lenght is -1, use intermediate progressbar :)

Comment: Don't call `setDoOutput(true)` unless you really are doing output, which you aren't. It sets the method to POST.

Answer (score 2):

Inspect the headers the server is sending. Very probably the server is sending `Transfer-Encoding: Chunked` and no `Content-Length` header at all. This is a common practice in HTTP/1.1. If the server isn't sending the length, the client obviously can't know it. If this is the case, and you have no control over the server code, the best thing to do is probably display a spinner type of indicator only.